# Function/method definition error in Arduion/C++. Or syntax error?

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors, arduino

I'm translating a program I wrote in Ruby to the Arduino/C++.  On my first attempt to define a function/method I keep getting the following error:  "BreadboardTestFunctions:41: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
BreadboardTestFunctions:91: error: expected `}' at end of input"

Hard to understand because the function-definition must be followed by a pair of brackets.  This could reflect a syntax error as it has persisted as I've corrected a score of errors in the function as I've tried to solve this problem. But it looks OK to me now.

I'm generating an output after matrix multiplication in the section beginning "// routine to multiply:  behavior=brain * stimulus'".  Although the problematic method, "mody" (at line 40) is only called once now, once I get it to work all the outputs will call it.

The code:

```
    /*  BREADBOARD
  Implement program on Arduino + breadboard
*/

// constants 
int foodPin = 2;     // to provide food
int painPin = 3;     // to punish
int ucsPin = 4;      // the UCS
int csPin = 5;       // the CS
int lightPin = 6;    // turn the "light" stim on/off
int thresh = 700;

// variables 
int buttonState = 0; // variable for reading the pushbutton status
boolean lighton = false;
unsigned short int energy = 10000;
int stimulus[11] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

int brain[7][11] = { {0,0,0,0,99,0,0,0,0,1,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,99,0,0,0,1,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,99,0,0,1,0},
                     {90,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,1,-99},
                     {0,90,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,1,1},
                     {0,0,90,0,0,0,0,1,-1,1,1},
                     {0,0,0,90,0,0,0,1,-1,1,1} };

int behavior[7] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

void setup() {
  // initialize the pushbutton pins as an input:
  pinMode(foodPin, INPUT); 
  pinMode(painPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ucsPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(csPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(lightPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int ix=0;

  // define behavioral methods
  void mody (int ix, int brain[], int stimulus[])
      { int psp=20;
        int j;
        for(j=7;j<11;j++)
    {if (brain[ix][j] > 0) brain[ix][j]+= stimulus[j] * (99-brain[ix][j])/psp;
     if (brain[ix][j] < 0) brain[ix][j]+= -1*(stimulus[j] * abs(99-brain[ix][j])/psp);}
         return;}

} // end void setup

void loop(){
  // decay stimulus vector.  do this and check inputs for ALL stimulii later
  int k;
  for(k=0;k<11;k++)
  {if (stimulus[k] > 1) stimulus[k]-=2; else stimulus[k]=0;}

  //check inputs

  buttonState = digitalRead(foodPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) stimulus[4] = 9;
  buttonState = digitalRead(painPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) stimulus[5] = 9;
  buttonState = digitalRead(ucsPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) stimulus[6] = 9;
  buttonState = digitalRead(lightPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {stimulus[7] = 9; stimulus[8] = 9;lighton = true;}
      else {stimulus[7] = 0; stimulus[8] = 0;lighton = false;}
  buttonState = digitalRead(ucsPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) stimulus[6] = 9;

// routine to multiply:  behavior=brain * stimulus'
int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {  behavior[i]=0;
       for (j=0;j<11;j++)
           {behavior[i]= behavior[i]+stimulus[j]*brain[i][j]; }
    } // end for i
    if (behavior[0] > thresh) {Serial.println("Positive Fixer");}
    if (behavior[1] > thresh) {Serial.println("Negative Fixer");}
    if (behavior[2] > thresh) {Serial.println("UCR"); mody (2, brain[], stimulus[]);}
    if (behavior[3] > thresh) {Serial.println("Operant one");}
    if (behavior[4] > thresh) {Serial.println("Operant two");}
    if (behavior[5] > thresh) {Serial.println("Operant three");}
    if (behavior[6] > thresh) {Serial.println("Operant four");}

// generate random operant
   if (random(energy) < 10) stimulus[random(4)]= 9 + random(3);

energy --;
Serial.println(energy);

}  // end void loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not define one function inside another function. It is what you are trying to do in the following code snippet

```
void setup() {
  // initialize the pushbutton pins as an input:
  pinMode(foodPin, INPUT); 
  pinMode(painPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ucsPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(csPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(lightPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int ix=0;

  // define behavioral methods
  void mody (int ix, int brain[], int stimulus[])
```

You are trying to define function mody inside function setup.

Comment: Ahh!  So I should define mody before setup then?